# What command does MPI run over SSH?

Tags: openmpi

I have OpenMPI installed and I'm running a script on multiple nodes with mpiexec. OpenMPI requires that the node I'm running the mpiexec command on have SSH access to the other nodes in the cluster.

What specifically does OpenMPI do over SSH to start the processes on the other nodes? It runs my MPI script, sure, but how does MPI run in such that each node is assigned a rank, for example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you are running under a (supported) resource manager (such as Slurm, PBS or other), the `plm/rsh` component will be used to start the MPI app.

Long story short, Open MPI uses a distributed virtual machine (DVM) to launch the MPI tasks. The first step is to have one daemon per node.
The initial "daemon" is `mpirun`, and then one `orted` daemon have to be remotely spawned on each other node, and this is where `plm/rsh` uses `SSH`.

By default, if you are running on less than 64 nodes, then `mpirun` will SSH to all the other nodes. But if you are running on a larger number of nodes, then `mpirun` will use a tree spawn algorithm, in which other nodes might ssh to other nodes.
Bottom line, if you are using `ssh` with Open MPI, and unless you are running on a small cluster with default settings, **all** nodes should be able to `ssh` passwordless to **all** nodes.

Comment: Thanks -- is there anything else that OpenMPI does over SSH? I'm in a situation where a command will be run on all my hosts, and I want the MPI program to run with the processes on the hosts finding each other rather than all be started by a process on one node that SSHs onto the others. Is this possible or am I talking nonsense?